# Sort list of words by words and by char in words

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Without using  `.sort()` or `sorted()`, I want to sort each word in this list by converting each character to a number, sorting the characters within the word, and then sorting the words. I feel like I've tried everything here. I know I need to convert them to lowercase then using `ord(letter) - 96` to get `3, 26261, 122, 211, 134, 2, 31, 22626, 218, 912`, then sort each "group" and then convert each group back to strings.

Input: `c zzA aBb bAa Acd B CA zzz ZR IL`
Output: `abb acd b   baa c   ca  il  zr  zza zzz`

Comment: You don't need to convert the letters to numbers. Just convert each string to lowercase and then sort the array.

Comment: Are you supposed to convert them to numbers or is that just your way of solving the problem?

Comment: assignment calls for no built-in functions. i have to write an algorithm to solve it.

Comment: can we use str.lower() ? or is that also not allowed?

Comment: that’s fine. loops, map, list comprehension etc all fine. i just have to write a sorting function so i can’t use built-in `sort` because that would be too easy ha

Comment: This looks like an assignment. While I answered your question, you should try to solve these yourself. It will help you learn python better. Trial and error and discovery is the heart of learning anything. That's what makes the learning process fun and exciting and builds curiosity

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this:

```
a = ["c", "zzA", "aBb", "bAa", "Acd", "B", "CA", "zzz", "ZR", "I"]
b = sorted([i.lower() for i in a])

print(b)
# ['abb', 'acd', 'b', 'baa', 'c', 'ca', 'i', 'zr', 'zza', 'zzz']
```

Comment: assignment calls for no built-in functions. i have to write an algorithm to solve it.

Comment: @jan, this solution changes the original list values to lower case. use key=str.lower to retain original value

Comment: @JoeFerndz How does this solution change the original list? I could not reproduce this after checking the output of `print(a)` (just before `print(b)`).

Answer (score 0):

## Without using sort function. Using loops and bubble sort

```
input_list = ['c','zzA','aBb','bAa','Acd','B','CA','zzz','ZR','IL']
for i in range(len(input_list)):
    for j in range (i+1,len(input_list)):
        if input_list[i].lower() > input_list[j].lower():
            input_list[i], input_list[j] = input_list[j], input_list[i]
print (input_list)
```

Output will be:

```
['aBb', 'Acd', 'B', 'bAa', 'c', 'CA', 'IL', 'ZR', 'zzA', 'zzz']
```

## Using Sort function with key=str.lower

You can also do this without doing a loop.  `list.sort(key=str.lower)` where `list` is the list of values.

```
>>> x = ['c','zzA','aBb','bAa','Acd','B','CA','zzz','ZR','IL']
>>> x=
['c', 'zzA', 'aBb', 'bAa', 'Acd', 'B', 'CA', 'zzz', 'ZR', 'IL']

>>> x.sort(key=str.lower)
>>> x
['aBb', 'Acd', 'B', 'bAa', 'c', 'CA', 'IL', 'ZR', 'zzA', 'zzz']
```

Comment: i can’t use “.sort()” or “sorted()”

Comment: got it. just saw your note on the other responses